# angular 5 stepper selectedIndex not working with variable set in subscribe

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I'm trying to get a stepper to go to a set question based on where the user left off. I'm using selectedIndex, and setting it to a number I retrieved from the server.

Html:

```
  <mat-horizontal-stepper class="my-stepper" [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" [selectedIndex]="currentQuestion">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let question of currentVideoCount">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Question {{question}}</ng-template>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

TypeScript:

```
  public currentVideoCount: number[];
  public currentQuestion: number;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.programId.subscribe((programId) => {
      this.evalService.getCurrentVideoCount(programId).subscribe(data => {
        this.currentVideoCount = data.videoCount;
        this.currentQuestion = data.question;
      });
    })
  }
```

This does not work. I get this error, if I do it this way.

```
ERROR Error: cdkStepper: Cannot assign out-of-bounds value to `selectedIndex`.
```

But, if I simply change the html to not use currentQuestion, and just use a number, or a variable that I define as 1, 2, etc. it does work. If I just put currentQuestion in an html tag, it gives me the correct number. If I log it anywhere, it gives me the correct number. But the stepper itself will not use the number, and only if the number is given to it this way. How do I get it to use currentQuestion for the selectedIndex? I assume it's going wrong because of the way I define it in a subscribe, but I don't know how to fix that.

Edit: If I initialize the currentQuestion to be the number I'm expecting data.question to be, it works, but not if I initialize it to something else. Obviously not what I want, but interesting none the less.

Edit: If I set the selectedIndex to be out of bounds by default, like 300 out of an array of 3 items, I do not get the out-of-bounds error, it just greys out the entire stepper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I came up with is putting the stepper in a div with an *ngIf, and in the subscribe after all the data has been set, allowing the div to be shown.

Html:

```
  <div *ngIf="!processing">
    <mat-horizontal-stepper class="my-stepper" [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" [selectedIndex]="currentQuestion">
      <mat-step *ngFor="let question of currentVideoCount">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Question {{question}}</ng-template>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </div>
```

Typescript:

```
  public currentVideoCount: number[];
  public currentQuestion: number;
  public processing = true;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadNextVideo();
    this.programId.subscribe((programId) => {
      this.evalService.getCurrentVideoCount(programId).subscribe(data => {
        this.currentVideoCount = data.videoCount;
        this.currentQuestion = data.question;
        this.processing = false;
      });
    })
  }
```

It's ugly, but it works. If anybody comes up with a better answer, please post it here.

Comment: I get my stepper data from an `@Input()` and still get this damn index out of bounds error using your solution. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution is perfectly valid, another alternative is to initialise the value of `currentQuestion` at the beginning, so that when we are still waiting for the subscribe is not undefined

```
public currentVideoCount: number[];
public currentQuestion: number = 0; // Initialise currentQuestion
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.programId.subscribe((programId) => {
      this.evalService.getCurrentVideoCount(programId).subscribe(data => {
        this.currentVideoCount = data.videoCount;
        this.currentQuestion = data.question;
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: I did try this, but it would never change to data.question in the subscribe. It would either give me the same error if data.question and the initialized number were different, or just be stuck on the initialized number if it was the same as data.question.